# How to add she bang at the beginning of all .sh files?

Tags: shell, shebang, file-manipulation

I want to edit she bang line `#!/bin/bash` line on the top of files in all the files with `.sh` extension how it done by scripting.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the sed command:

```
sed -i "1i #!/bin/bash" *.sh
```

- `sed`: name of the command
- `-i` : sed option to edit the file
  inplace
- `1` : line number
- `i` : to do the insertion before the
  line number provided before
- `#!/bin/bash`: the shebang to be
  added
- `*.sh`: to make this work on all .sh
  files

Comment: its works for existing and newly created sh files is there any option that it impact only on newly created sh files not disturbing the previous ones

Comment: No, there is not such option for sed. You'll have to use **find** combined with this sed to modify only newly created files.

Comment: can u please suggest how to use sed with find "by showing example" i mean is this possible by using ctime options or what

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path -iname "*.sh" -type f -exec sed -i.bak '1i #!/bin/bash' "{}" +;
```

Comment: what does i.bak option used for

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how this can be achieved:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "New file name?"
read -r name
touch $name
echo "'$name' created"
cp shebang.txt "$name"
chmod +x "$name"
```

I use a simple text file containing only the shebang.